# While incrementing a pointer which points to an array, why does my array feels be reversed?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

When I'm dereferencing and printing the output of a given array pointer, I'm getting my array in reverse.
Here's the code

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4};
    int* ptr = arr;
    cout<<ptr<<endl;
    cout<<*ptr++<<endl;
    cout<<*ptr<<" "<<*ptr++<<" "<<*ptr++<<" "<<*ptr++;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0x61fee8
1
0 4 3 2
```

But since I filled the array in increasing order and incremented the pointer I was expecting the output to be as
`1 2 3 4`

and why there is a zero in 2nd line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: TL;DR Configure your compiler to use C++17, or split the last `cout` to separate statements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that the size of the array is 5 and the number of initialization elements is 4, which means that the last element will be initialized to 0.

The reason for unordered output is that C++ compiler does not guarantee the order in which the parameters of `<<` are evaluated. It means that, in your last `cout`, it is possible that the third `ptr++` is evaluated before the first one.

If you replace your last `cout` with multiple `cout`s as follows, you will see that the code works as you expect.

```
cout<< *ptr;
cout<< *ptr++;
cout<< *ptr++;
cout<< *ptr++;
```

Comment: which order would result in `0` being the first number to be printed ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, For example, the reverse order. when the *ptr is evaluated after all "*ptr++"s are evaluated. In that case, the fifth element of the array (which does not exist) is printed, and since the value that is stored in that location is unknown, it is probably 0 in the specific run that the questioner has sent. Note that the code in total has four "ptr++"s.

Comment: You should mention that this was fixed in C++17.

Comment: yeah, sorry for not being clear. I actually wanted to point out that the answer is incomplete. 4 increments and dereferencing the pointer is undefined behavior

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I wouldn't say "fixed" but rather specified, mandated, or defined.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: You sure about that: `arr[4]` is zero.

Comment: @Bathsheba oh I am not so sure anymore

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - what was fixed and in what way?

Comment: @pm100 See rule 19 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). In short, the first operand of `<<` and `>>` is now sequenced before the second operand.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ty

Comment: I got it, Thanks for your answers and inpouts fellas